# TypeScript error compiling Map

Tags: typescript

```
let a : any;
let m = new Map<any, any>(Object.keys(a).map(prop => ([prop.x, prop.y])));
```

with `esnext` target produces the error

> file: 'file:///c%3A/GIT/MainLine/members/src/tasks/list/decTest2.ts'
>   severity: 'Error'
>   message: 'Argument of type 'any[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<[any, any]>'.
>     Types of property '[Symbol.iterator]' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => IterableIterator' is not assignable to type '() => Iterator<[any, any]>'.
>         Type 'IterableIterator' is not assignable to type 'Iterator<[any, any]>'.
>           Types of property 'next' are incompatible.
>             Type '(value?: any) => IteratorResult' is not assignable to type '(value?: any) => IteratorResult<[any, any]>'.
>               Type 'IteratorResult' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<[any, any]>'.
>                 Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '[any, any]'.
>                   Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]'.'
>   at: '4,27'
>   source: 'ts'

which is strange because

`let m2 = new Map<any, any>([[1, 2], [2, 3], ['a', 'b']])`

compiles fine.  What do I need to add to the first sample to get it to compile?

Note that I do know that

`let m2 = new Map<any, any>(<any>[[1, 2], [2, 3], ["a", 'b']])`

will also fix it, but I'd like to understand why this errors out, and see if there's a more decent fix.

Comment: prop is a string. Are you sure you didn't mean to write a[prop].x instead of prop.x?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript doesn't know for sure if your array is meant to be a tuple or a plain array in that context. Type argument inference tries to only use its arguments as inference sites.

As a result, when calling `map`, it doesn't draw an inference from the type of the parameter of `new Map<any, any>(...)`) to the return type of `map`.

TypeScript 2.4 is making [some changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16072) in this direction, and [your specific scenario was brought up](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16072#issuecomment-304776586). Discussion and progress on the issue itself can be [tracked here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11152).

As a workaround, you can write an explicit return type

```
(prop): [any, any] => [prop.x, prop.y]
```

or you can give `map` an explicit type argument

```
Object.keys(a).map<[any, any]>(...)
```

Note that in either case, TypeScript catches the error that `x` and `y` are not valid properties on `string`s.

Comment: plus 1 - thanks!  I'll leave this open a bit but those links are particularly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it the compiler simply cannot infer the expected type for `map<U>` if you set it explicitly, its fine:

```
let a: any;
let b = Object.keys(a).map<[any, any]>(key => [key, a[key]]);    
let m = new Map<any, any>(b);
```

the problem is that it is giving up and returning `any[][]` which is invalid for the expected type tuple: `[any, any][]`

Comment: oh neat - I didn't know Array.prototype.map could take generic type arguments

Answer (score 2):

The key here is the type of what your `map` callback function is returning.

```
prop => [prop.x, prop.y]
```

TypeScript doesn't automatically infer tuple types from array literals like the array you're returning—it'll instead assume a regular array type (in this case, `any[]`) which means your call to `map` will return an array of *that* type (in this case, `any[][]`).

The `Map` object constructor, however, is expecting an array of a specific tuple type. In this instance, it'll be looking for an array or iterable of `[any, any]` (we'll call that `[any, any][]` for simplicity).

Since TypeScript doesn't automatically infer the tuple type from the array you're creating in `map`, the quickest way to satisfy the typechecker is to specify the return value of the function to show that you intend it to be used as a tuple:

```
(prop): [any, any] => [prop.x, prop.y]
```

With the callback's return value type being explicitly set, `map` will return a value of type `[any, any][]` which satisfies the `Map` constructor.

Comment: plus 1 - thanks a ton.  I'll leave the post open for a bit, but solid info - thanks!